# How can i implement Facebook and Google login witout using Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a simple database and user model which includes fullname,Email,Password,Gender,Birthday.I'm still developing the model according to needs. 
I would like to design my own simple membership system because asp.net identity becomes for me a little bit confusing .I read articles but most of them are told on Asp.net MVC Template.
I had done a login form for registration.It save user informations to db.user by using EF.
Now i would like to implement Facebook and Google login for registration.How can i do?

Comment: As far I as know, Facebook/google login has nothing to do with ASP.Net identity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct coupling between the Facebook/Google owin authentication middleware and the Asp.Net Identity system. In the MVC template, they are tied together by the `AccountController`.

To use the external authentication middleware without ASP.NET Identity you would typically first issue a `AuthenticationResponseChallenge` by calling `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider)`. In the MVC template that is done in the `ChallengeResult` class, which you can just copy into your own solution.

Then, you need to take care of the returned response which is done in the `AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback()` action method in the template. Just write your own, that instead of communicating with ASP.NET Identity communicates with your own implementation.

In my [Understanding the Owin External Authentication Pipeline blog post](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/understanding-the-owin-external-authentication-pipeline/) there are more details on how external authentication works.